# When I using sublime and emacs as the development tool for scala, there are some errors occured

Tags: emacs, ensime

I use the sublime open the ensime project, the ensime server started normal. 
After using it for a short time, the following errors occured.

Handling RPC: (swank:completions D:\Scala\ensime\src\main\scala\Main.scala 52 0)
Writing: 000086(:return (:abort 202 "Malformed swank:completions call: (swank:completions D:\Scala\ensime\src\main\scala\Main.scala 52 0)") 21)
Error in socket reader: java.io.EOFException: End of file reached in socket reader.
Got connection, creating handler...

---

When i use Emacs,from inside emacs，execute M-x ensime.the following errors occured.

d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime>set CLASSPATH="d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ant-1.6.5.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ant-1.8.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ant-launcher-1.8.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\asm-3.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\asm-commons-3.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\asm-tree-3.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\critbit-0.0.4.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ensime_2.9.2-RC1-0.9.3.RC4.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ivy-2.1.0.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.0.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-artifact-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-model-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-profile-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-project-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-repository-metadata-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-settings-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.6.0.v_A58.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\org.scala-refactoring_2.9.2-SNAPSHOT-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\scala-compiler.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\scalariform_2.9.1-0.1.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-file-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar"

d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime>if "" == "" (set ENSIME_JVM_ARGS=-Xms256M -Xmx1512M -XX:PermSize=128m -Xss1M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 )

d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime>java -classpath "d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ant-1.6.5.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ant-1.8.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ant-launcher-1.8.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\asm-3.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\asm-commons-3.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\asm-tree-3.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\critbit-0.0.4.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ensime_2.9.2-RC1-0.9.3.RC4.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\ivy-2.1.0.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.0.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-artifact-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-model-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-profile-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-project-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-repository-metadata-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\maven-settings-2.2.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.6.0.v_A58.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\org.scala-refactoring_2.9.2-SNAPSHOT-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\scala-compiler.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\scalariform_2.9.1-0.1.1.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-file-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar;d:\myemacs.emacs.d\ensime\bin\..\lib\xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar" -Xms256M -Xmx1512M -XX:PermSize=128m -Xss1M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.ensime.server.Server c:/Users/zxu/AppData/Local/Temp/ensime_port.5320 
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Process *inferior-ensime-server* exited abnormally with code 1

---

This problem troubled me for a long time，I can't sleep if these two problems were not be resolved.
Thanks！

My system environment：
OS:     Window 7 64bit
JAVA:   1.7 or 1.6
Scala:  2.9.1 final
Sbt:    0.11.3
Ensime: ensime_2.9.2-RC1-0.9.3.RC4.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your Java's bin directory to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: %JAVA_HOME%\bin should be in the path. What does executing "java" from cmd.exe print ?

Comment: PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\eclipse\java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;D:\eclipse\scala-2.9.2\bin;D:\Scala\sbt\
;D:\eclipse\java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;